# Review and rating implementation of the doctor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-fullstack

Issue: State variable inside a api call is not getting updated

Description: Hi I am trying to implement the doctor review part of the application. where anyone can write the review of the doctor. when i am writing the review on submission of review  am calling review creation api using axios.post inside then i am trying to update the review count state variable but it is not getting updated it is showing old value not the latest one
initial review count =1
submit a new review
review count should be 2
but when logging it is showing 1

how can i call a single api call to update review count inside the submit review. currently i am calling put api 2 times to update review count and recommendation review count
also i want to update doctor object with reviewcount and reco review count and pass this other page
doctor={...doctor,review_count:reviewcount,recommendation_count:recoreviewcount}
navigation.navigate("DoctorDetail",doctor);

as state variable is not getting updated it is holding the old value
review_count:reviewcount,recommendation_count:recoreviewcount

```
Example code....
----------


const ShareYourStory = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const doctor = route.params;
  const [recovalue, setRecoValue] = useState();
  const [waittimevalue, setWaitTimeValue] = useState(0);
  const [isfriendliness, setFriendliness] = useState(false);
  const [isexplainhealthissue, setExpIssue] = useState(false);
  const [issatisfaction, setSatisfaction] = useState(false);
  const [issue, setIssue] = useState("");
  const [reviewcomment, setReviewComment] = useState("");
  const [reviewcount, setReviewCount] = useState(0);
  const [recoreviewcount, setRecoReviewCount] = useState(0);
```

//comment

```
  const submitFeedback = () => {
    console.log("submit patient feedback");
    console.log('reviewcountstatus',reviewcountstatus,'recoreviewcountstatus',recoreviewcountstatus);


    var most_happy_about = "";

    if (isfriendliness)
      most_happy_about = most_happy_about + "Doctor Friendliness,";
    if (isexplainhealthissue)
      most_happy_about = most_happy_about + "Explaination of Health Issue,";
    if (issatisfaction)
      most_happy_about = most_happy_about + "Treatment satisfaction";

    var reviewer_name = "Vikram";

    let reviewinfo = {
      doctor: `${doctor._id}`,
      reviewer_name: `${reviewer_name}`,
      is_doctor_recommended: `${recovalue}`,
      review: `${reviewcomment}`,
      issue_for_visit: `${issue}`,
      most_happy_about: `${most_happy_about}`,
    };
    //console.log(reviewinfo);
    axios
      .post(`${host}/api/v1/reviews`, reviewinfo)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status == 201) {
          // fetch no of review count from review table based on doctor id
          var reviewurl = `${host}/api/v1/reviews?doctor=${doctor._id}`;
          console.log("reviewurl", reviewurl);
          axios
            .get(reviewurl)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log("reviewcount", res.data.count);
              if (res.data.count > 0) {
                setReviewCount(res.data.count);
                const updatereviewcount = {
                  review_count: `${reviewcount}`   
                };

                axios
                .put(`${host}/api/v1/doctors/${doctor._id}`, updatereviewcount)
                .then((res) => {
                    if(res.status == 200 || res.status == 201) {
                      console.log('status',res.data);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                   console.log('error',error);
                })
         
              }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });

          // calculate doctor_recommended_percent value
          var recoreviewurl = `${host}/api/v1/reviews?doctor=${doctor._id}&is_doctor_recommended=Yes`;
          console.log("recoreviewurl", recoreviewurl);
          axios
            .get(recoreviewurl)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log("recoreviewcount", res.data.count);
              if (res.data.count > 0) {
                setRecoReviewCount(res.data.count);
                const updaterecoreviewcount = {
                  doctor_recommended_percent: `${recoreviewcount}`   
                };

                axios
                .put(`${host}/api/v1/doctors/${doctor._id}`, updaterecoreviewcount)
                .then((res) => {
                    if(res.status == 200 || res.status == 201) {
                      console.log('status',res.data);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                   console.log('error',error);
                })
              }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });

            console.log(recoreviewcountstatus,reviewcountstatus);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {

        console.log("feedback review creation failed", err);
      });

  };
```

}

Comment: does the value `res.data.count` console log fine?

Comment: yes it is showing correct value if log reviewcount it is showing old value

Comment: is your `submitFeedback` funcion called after a form submission ? maybe you are not cancelling the default form submit event and the page gets reloaded. Thus, causing a state reset.